# why do I get a 404 Error when using PFDAVAdmin to connect to Exchange 2007 on Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, exchange-2007, exchange

When I connect to all mailboxes using PFDAVADMIN to my exchange 2007 server I get a list of all the userse but when I expand any of the users I get the following error

Could not expand http://server.local/exadmin/admin/PGW.LOCAL/mbx/user@domain.com/non_ipm_subtree/: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.

Comment: Any chance it's due to connecting via plain HTTP? Unless that's a typo, it may be the issue.

Comment: in the connection options I'm not sure where you would specify https.... i just put the name of the server

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same problem a while ago, what I did was :

I logged on to my workstation (Windows7) on the same Subnet / Domain as Exchange.

On the connect window for PFDavAdmin, I specified DNS Names for Exchange Server and Global Catalog Server, `Authenticate as Currently Logged on User`

It worked straightaway for Public Folders and Mailboxes.

Try that if you haven't already - it will be good if your workstation and your exchange server are on the same domain (ofcourse) and using the same DNS server.

Hope that Helps

Comment: They are on the same Domain/DNS Server. How exactly did you Speicify the DNS Names?

Comment: servername.domainname.local or whatever it is in your environment.
globalcatalogservername.domainname.local

Comment: Yes the exchange & Global Cagalog servers are actually the same server and have been specified as follows

SERVER.pgw.local